# Modal not working since update to Materialize 0.98.0

Tags: jquery, materialize

I have a problem with materializeCSS. I just updated from 0.97.5 to 0.98.0 and modals don't work anymore.

I change the way they are initialized according to documentation.

Jquery version is 3.1.1 and it's loaded before materialize.

Here's my code :

**Initialisation :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.modal').modal();
    });
```

**Modal** :

```
<a class="modal-trigger" href="#delete">
    <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
</a>


<div id="delete" class="modal">
    <nav class="top-nav panel-title truncate">Confirmer la suppression</nav>
    <p class="modal-content"></p>
    <div class="modal-footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried   `$('.modal').modal('open');` may be this gonna work

Comment: Doesn't work either

Comment: check your console as well what it says?

Comment: I've no error in console

Comment: When I copy-paste the example from the doc on the same page, the button triggers the modal but I don't see it and my page is hidden as if the modal was shown. I don't even have this with my own code

Comment: You say in the question you are using jQuery 3.1.1. Are you sure? Your code works with jQuery 2.1.1, which materializecss specifies. See http://codepen.io/davep/pen/YNELaq

Comment: I think it was a cache problem. I tried again the day after I asked the question and it was working without changeing anything.

Answer (score 2):

The key point that docs doesn't make accent that you should initialize all modals first. `$('.modal').modal();`

Full working code for modals should look like this

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {

        //initialize all modals           
        $('.modal').modal();

        //now you can open modal from code
        $('#modal1').modal('open');

        //or by click on trigger
        $('.trigger-modal').modal();

    }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```